# pandas, matplotlib, drawing a stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Names   loc.items
Name1   343 1756
Name2   5   15
Name3   688 1667
Name4   88  444
Name5   1   1
....
Name99  22  111
```

It is easy to get a stacked bar where the names are on x axis and the stacked bar is on every name.

I want to get it the other way around. I want two stacked bars with 99 stacks(names inside) for location and items. Like the table itself. Each stack pair of a Name(x) has a thickness of loc.(x) and items(x) How can I make this chart?

This:

```
myclist[[ myclist.loc[:,"names"]]].plot(x='carrier', kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

or this approach

```
# plot data in stack manner of bar type
df.plot(x='Carrier', kind='bar', stacked=True,
        title='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe')
plt.show()
```

does not work.
If the dataframe look like below, it would work.
But written (manually) as series 'location' and 'items' and separate 'columns' it works. I thought it should be the same thing but it seems not so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['location', 10, 20, 10, 26], ['items', 20, 25, 15, 21]],
                  columns=['Names', 'Name1', 'Name2','Name3', 'Name99'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYTNg.png)

Comment: "*does not work*" -> **How?**, please provide the output/error and explain what you would like to have (eventually with a mockup graph)

Comment: `df.plot(x='Names', kind='bar', stacked=True) ` ?

Comment: There should be a graph in my post.

Comment: I do not want 99 stacked bars with two stacks each. I want two large bars with 99 stacks each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but I think there is many rows, so ouput for 100 rows is not readable:

```
df.set_index('Names').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image: pic]

One possible idea is filter names, here between `Name1` and `Name4`:

```
df.set_index('Names').loc['Name1':'Name4'].T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Comment: myclist=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/A692517/PhytonStuff/myClist.xlsx')

Comment: myclist.set_index('Names').iloc[1:6].T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
Almost there, but somehow now I have three stacked bars (Names, Locations and items). I only want two bars(Locations and Items)

Comment: @Jodahsh Use `myclist.set_index('Names')[['loc', 'items']].iloc[1:6].T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`

Comment: My answer was not clearly written down.
Almost there, I got the stacked bars, but thre of them. The indexed "Names" has been printet as stacked bar as well. 
Your answer is correct, but pls. help me to get the "Names" bar out of the plot.

the code:


myclist.set_index('names').iloc[1:len(myclist)].T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 2.3),
          ncol=3, fancybox=True, shadow=True)